# Blurry SpriteFont on monogame (Win8)

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, monogame, spritefont

i have a really weird problem, i'm trying to print a simple spritefont on screen but the sprite is getting really blurry...

I have loaded the spritefont from VS 2010 using content pipeline to form the xnb file then load it to VS2012 under monogame

```cs
public void DrawText(int x, int y, string s)
    {
        _color = Color.White;
        _rotation = 0.0f;
        _size = 1.0f;
        _spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        _spriteBatch.DrawString(_spriteFont, s, new Vector2(x, y), _color, _rotation, new Vector2(), _size, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
        _spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

still the image is getting really blurry.. i have no idea why...

i'm talking about somethinglike this

[image]

does anyone knows why this could be? i have searched through everything and the closest answer i got is that if the sprite or spritefont position is a float (non exact int) the result will be alliased... but this is not the case here

Cheers!

I uploaded the XNB sprite font
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=50E25A0EEED51C3C!241&authkey=!AAvw-i5OtipT8fo
if anyone is interested in trying this

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, try setting SamplerState.PointClamp in SpriteBatch.Begin.

Comment: did that.. didn't change much... XNA shows no problems when doing this

Comment: Oh? In that case I think you've found a bug in MonoGame. Report it on the MonoGame forums and perhaps link back to this question.

Comment: Have you tried to change the spritefont and see if the blur effect remains?

Comment: I changed the font properties and also re compiled the xnb file, no changed... will try again in the afternoon (this notebook doesn't have mono installed)

Comment: On monogame i got this reply:  Ya it looks weird on mine as well. (Windows DX)


I've seen this before (Like in general not in MG)... it looks like incorrect flipping of a DXT texture.

Comment: Try drawing a background behind your string, it seems so strange, I've drawn strings so many time and I've never had any problem.

Comment: Check to see if your X/Y positions are whole numbers. if they arnt round them to the nearest integer.

Comment: are you drawing any thing else to the screen at the same time? as I was getting a similar issue due to the drawing order in xna

Comment: Are you using a released version of monogame or building against develop? If its develop, make sure you pull down the latest and try running/building against it. If its not develop... well maybe try develop.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem has been resolved upstream.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed in 3.8.1.